# Use of command line argument shows array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

When I try to execute the below code, it shows array index out of bounds exception.

```
public class aaags {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The length of args is:"+ args.length);
        System.out.println("The value of args[0] is:"+ args[0]);
        System.out.println("The value of args[1] is:"+ args[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: You have to pass arguments to the `main()`. What arguments are you using to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check `args.length` (or use `for ( : )`)

```
System.out.println("The length of args is:" + args.length);
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    System.out.println("The value of args[" + i + "] is:" + args[i]);
```